# Error : file does not begin with ' pdf-' asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to open the PDF on clicking a link in browser. It is actually from DB as BLOB. But i am getting Error : file does not begin with ' pdf-' asp.net

This is the code i am using,

```
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)

        {

            string strExtenstion = dt.Rows[0]["DGN0101FILE_EXTENSION"].ToString();

            byte[] bytFile = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["DGN0101FILE"];

            string fileName = dt.Rows[0]["DGN0101FILE_NAME"].ToString();

            Response.Clear();

            Response.ClearContent();

            Response.ClearHeaders();

            Response.Buffer = true;

            if (strExtenstion == ".doc" || strExtenstion == ".docx")
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
            }
            else if (strExtenstion == ".xls" || strExtenstion == ".xlsx")
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            }
            else if (strExtenstion == ".pdf")
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            } 
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytFile.Length.ToString());
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytFile); 
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
            Response.Clear();
        }
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error?  In the code (if so, on what line)?  Or in the PDF reader on the client after the code is finished executing?

Comment: @David, getting this error after the code is excecuted. it actually shows me a dialog box to open or save the PDF. When i open it gives me the Error : file does not begin with ' pdf-' asp.net

Comment: Then it sounds like it's not a PDF file.  If the code finishes and the data is transferred byte-for-byte to the client, then it's working as designed.  Given the information so far, it's highly likely that the byte stream in question isn't a valid PDF file.  (That is, it doesn't contain a file header that the PDF reader uses to identify a valid PDF file.)  Might be worth trying to open it with different applications, or examine it in something like Notepad to see if there's useful header information.

Comment: You can try to save the result file on the disc and then just to compare the content and length of the original and result files.

Comment: I guess the content of pdf file is not stored properly into BLOB field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A valid PDF file starts with `%PDF-1.5` or similar. My guess is that your data is not being stored or retrieved properly.

- View the original file in Acrobat/Acrobat Reader to ensure it's actually a PDF.
- View the original file in a text editor and visually inspect it.
- Check the database table to ensure that there is binary data in the row.
- Check the length of the byte array being extracted from the database.